# How to draw 2 concentric circles?

Tags: java, swing

I don't really have any code yet except my only circle that draws in a JFrame. I have to draw 2 circles, an inner and outer, that form a ring. The starting point of the circles is (50, 50). The outer ring must be twice the width of the inner ring and the starting RING_WIDTH of the outer circle is 40.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First off, try writing code that can paint a circle with a specified center.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you can draw one circle why can't you draw two circles. All you do is change the parameters of the drawing method to draw the second circle.

Comment: Take a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254551/jslider-advice-needed/19256985#19256985). It might help you to find the appropriate coordinates.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the parameters for the second circle and I don't know how to find it. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted most of this code from here, the first google result: http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2008/12/draw-circle-in-jframe.html

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class DrawCirclesInJFrame extends JFrame {
    public static final int INNER_WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int OUTER_WIDTH = 40;

    public DrawCirclesInJFrame() {
        super("Draw Circles In JFrame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.drawOval(50-INNER_WIDTH/2, 50-INNER_WIDTH/2, INNER_WIDTH, INNER_WIDTH);
        g.drawOval(50-OUTER_WIDTH/2, 50-OUTER_WIDTH/2, OUTER_WIDTH, OUTER_WIDTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawCirclesInJFrame dlijf = new DrawCirclesInJFrame();
    }
}
```

Both are centered at 50,50.  Inner circle is diameter/width of 20, and outer circle is twice that, at 40.

NOTE: This answer assumes by "starting point", you meant "center point".

Comment: That doesn't center the second ring inside the first. That's my problem. There is some calculation that I just can't figure out to center the inner circle.